# i can't import preprocess from arabert.preprocess_arabert

Tags: python, libraries

```
import pandas as pd
from farasa.segmenter import FarasaSegmenter
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
from arabert.preprocess_arabert import never_split_tokens, preprocess
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

i get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arabert.preprocess_arabert'
please help me to solve this problem !

Comment: Did you install the package?

Comment: According to the [library repo](https://github.com/aub-mind/arabert/tree/432f3f5b914a08fce071386d09d04c971ca2e944/examples/old), the `preprocess_arabert` submodule was removed in v2.

Comment: yes, i did :                                                                                                                    
!pip install transformers
!pip install farasapy
!pip install pyarabic
!git clone https://github.com/aub-mind/arabert

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not too late, but here's a fix for future reference :

```
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor, never_split_tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a contradiction in your code and error. Your code is importing `arabert.prerpocess` and the error you have posted in question is indicating import error in `arabert.preprocess_arabert`. If your actual code contains import like `arabert.preprocess_arabert` then change it to `arabert.prerpocess` because they have updated it in `repository`.

If error still occurs, then As you said in comment that you have already run

```
!git clone https://github.com/aub-mind/arabert.git
```

before running error line

```
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor
```

then most probably you are not in same directory.

Check your current working directory using `os.getcwd()` and verify you have cloned repo in same directory.